# How knows Stream.toArray(Book[]::new); how many elements the array has and where is the implementation of “Book[]::new”

Tags: java, arrays, stream, java-stream, method-reference

I'm triying to understand method references and I don't know how with this "Book[]::new" it can create an
array with the right number of elements.

```
Book[] arrayBook = stBooks.toArray(Book[]::new);
```

In order to create the array when I use the second and third option I have to specify a Functional Interface
that Receive an Int and return a new Array.

But, in the first option I don't know where is the implementation and where you specify the number or
elements that is going to have the array. I figure that it create a new array element for each Stream element
but if I understand well you have to provide the implementation and "Book[]::new" doesn't have it.

```
Book book1 = new Book("ESDLA");
Book book2 = new Book("Harry Potter");
Stream<Book> stBooks = Stream.of(book1, book2);


1. Method References
Book[] arrayBook = stBooks.toArray(Book[]::new);

2. With Lambda Implementation
Book[] arrayBook1 = stBooks.toArray( (numElements) -> new Book[numElements] );

3. With Implementation
Book[] arrayBook2 = stBooks.toArray( new IntFunction<Book[]>() {

    @Override
    public Book[] apply(int numElements) {
        return new Book[numElements];
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the question? You have figured it right.

Answer (score 4):

This is a special case in the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1):

> If the method reference expression has the form `ArrayType::new`, a single notional method is considered. The method has a single parameter of type `int`, returns the `ArrayType`, and has no throws clause. If n = 1, this is the only potentially applicable method; otherwise, there are no potentially applicable methods.

[And also](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1):

> If the form is `Type[]^k :: new` (k ≥ 1), then the body of the invocation method has the same effect as an array creation expression of the form `new Type [ size ] []^k-1`, where `size` is the invocation method's single parameter. (The notation `[]^k` indicates a sequence of k bracket pairs.)

So the "implementation" that you want to find is hidden somewhere in the Java compiler, as it's all "compiler magic".

Comment: Could you explain what "the invocation method's single parameter" means? It is unclear to me how `size` is deduces. Is it number of elements in Stream?

Comment: @Amongalen `Book[]::new` is a method reference, representing an "invocation method". That method has a single parameter, as per the first quote. That single parameter is called `size` in the second quote.

Comment: @Amongalen The argument passed is "the size of the desired array", according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-).

Comment: @Sweeper I think I have finally understood this... thanks a lot!

The resume could be:

Is a special case and always that the compiler find Book[]::new in that context, it is going to create a new array with the length desired but you don't specify the length, the compiler decide it from the number of elements of the Stream.
I see this like "SYNTACTIC SUGAR"

Comment: The key word is "DESIRED", as you said in the previous comment - The argument passed is "the size of the desired array" - But not desired for you but desired for the compiler to satisfy the methods.

Every time, creating and implementing lambdas, methods, Interfaces... and suddenly in this case is not neccessary implementation... "compiler magic" what I try to avoid.

Thank you!

Comment: @Marquake I now suspect that you might now understand what [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) are... You shouldn't avoid them you know...

Comment: @Marquake the compiler doesn’t know how many elements the stream has. The Stream knows. `Book[]::new` produces exactly the same code as `numElements -> new Book[numElements]`. No magic.

Comment: @Holger the OP seems to understand that method references and lambdas are interchangeable. What I think they are confused about is the lack of the parameter `numElements`. In both a lambda and anonymous class, you declare a parameter, but in a method reference, you don’t. That’s why they said “I don’t know where you specify the number of elements...”.