# Which class's constructor is called for the Person[]::new

Tags: java

For the following code:

```java
Person[] men = people.stream()
                     .filter(p -> p.getGender() == MALE)
                     .toArray(Person[]::new);
```

I don't understand `Person[]::new` here, Which class (an array class)'s constructor is called here? Looks this constructor accepts an int value as array size.

Comment: Does [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123253/how-knows-stream-toarraybooknew-how-many-elements-the-array-has-and-where/65123412?) help?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/40902361/3020903 explains quite well what toArray does

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java stream toArray() convert to a specific type of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902315/java-stream-toarray-convert-to-a-specific-type-of-array)

Answer (score 1):

It's `int i -> new Person [i]` .

Comment: Thanks @danju. Stream<Person>.toArray(IntFunction) only provides a Person object to the s IntFunction(int i -> new Person[i],as you said), which actually wants an `Int`,so that compiling error should occur？

Comment: @Tom  how do you mean? It collects all person objects in the stream and puts it into the array created by the constructor. If there is only one person in the stream, the array will have size 1.

Answer (score 1):

The `toArray` method has the following signature:

```java
<A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator);
```

An `IntFunction` takes a primitive int (supplied by the `Stream` implementation) and maps it to an object of the supplied generic type, in this case an array of type `A`, which is whatever return type you pass to it either as a lambda expression or method reference (or even a concrete class, though that's rather verbose).

With that in mind, the method reference `Person[]::new` is equivalent to the lambda expression `(int i) -> new Person[i]`.

`i` in this particular case will be given the value of the size of the Stream, and the resulting array will be populated with the `Person` objects in the Stream.

Comment: Hi, @jeroen-steenbeeke,  I didn't understand this statement: `An IntFunction takes a primitive int (supplied by the Stream implementation)`. Stream<Person>.toArray(IntFunction) only provides a Person object to the `IntFunction`, which actually wants Int,so that compiling error should occur?

Comment: `IntFunction<R>` is a functional interface that defines a method `R apply(int value);`. That means the input is `int` and the output is `R`. So if the type is `IntFunction<Person[]>` then your input is `int` and your output is an array of `Person`. The `toArray` method *does not* in fact provide *any* `Person` objects to this `IntFunction`, since it has no methods that accept `Person` objects.

Answer (score 0):

`SomeClass::SomeMethod` is a *method reference*. Its an easier way to write the lambda `() -> SomeClass.SomeMethod()`.

If the method takes a parameter, say an `int`, the corresponsding lambda would be `i -> SomeClass.SomeMethod(i)`.

`Person[]::new` is a special type of method reference, in that '::new' references a *constructor*. Its a magic value for that.

`Person::new` is a more concise form of `i -> new Person[i]`. Note that this does not involve the constructor of `Person` at all, but of `Person[]`! This is a significant difference.

`IntFunction<R>` is a so called *functional interface*. Every lambda that accepts an int and returns an R is valid as instance for this.

`Stream#toArray` is defined as follows: `<A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator);`. In your case, you already have a `Stream<Person>`, thus it becomes `<Person> Person[] toArray(IntFunction<Person[]> generator);`.

Thus, this method accepts `Person[]::new`, since as explained above, that is a function that accepts an `int` and returns an `Person[]` (of length i).

The method uses the lambda to generate the properly sized array and populates it with the stream content.